# NU1603 adding Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Orders package

Tags: sitecore-commerce, commerce-engine

While adding a package reference to Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Orders, I see the following error:

> NU1603: Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Availability 2.1.3 depends on Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog (>= 2.1.9) but Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog 2.1.9 was not found. An approximate best match of Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog 2.1.10 was resolved.

What's causing this error and how can I fix it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

tl;dr Explicitly add `Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog 2.1.10` to the project and then re-add the intended package.

For whatever reason, Sitecore never published 2.1.9 of Sitecore.Commerce.Plugin.Catalog to the public NuGet feed instead skipping straight to 2.1.10. This becomes an issue when other packages depend on 2.1.9. When NuGet resolves *downstream* dependencies it won't accept the actual referenced version missing, even if the version dependency is fuzzy (`>= 2.1.9` in this case). If, on the other hand, the project already references the downstream dependency and *that* version is acceptable then it is considered valid.